# How do print term image field as background style attribute in views-view.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, views, theming

How do print term image field as background style attribute in views-view.tpl.php or in views-view-unformatted.tpl.php file?
I have view which lists terms of taxonomy vocabulary. All terms have title and image fields. I need to lists terms like:

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://example.com/term1_field_image.jpg);">
<h2>Title</h2>
<div>
<div style="background-image:url(http://example.com/term2_field_image.jpg);">
<h2>Title</h2>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with row style instead. Go to your views advance settings then click on theming information and look for appropriate name for row styling and write something like this.

```
$uriImagefromView = $row->field_field_image[0]['rendered']['#item']['uri'];
$urlImagefromView = file_create_url($uriImagefromView);
```

This will give you the url to the path of that image. Now you can easily render it as background.

If you want to render your background image in particular size you created in image style you can do like this

```
$resized_url = image_style_url('<style_name>', $uriImagefromView);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But I get new issue. If I print image as style="background image" path to file looks like <div style="background-image: url(" http:="" hosting-test.net="" sites="" default="" files="" styles="" max="" public="" collections="" 12140823_909452152472075_7251903571632437699_n_0.jpg?itok="pten85kT);&quot;"></div> what I missed?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What is your url looks like?

Comment: <div style="background-image: url(" http:="" hosting-test.net="" sites="" default="" files="" styles="" max="" public="" collections="" picture.jpg?itok="pten85kT);&quot;"></d‌​iv>     instead of     <div style="background-image: url(" http://hosting-test.net/sites/default/files/styles/max/public/collections/picture.jpg></d‌​iv>     In url no any slashes..

Comment: does the function return correct url?

Comment: Yes. If I render url outside style="" all is ok. If I render url in as style - have no slashes. <?php print '<div class="slide-bg" style="background-image: url("'.$resized_url.');"></div>'; ?>

Comment: It should work, I am not sure why it has been giving issue